# How to represent a three-dimensional operator with sympy properly?

Tags: sympy

I'm confused about how to correctly represent 3D operators, such as the position operator and the angular momentum operator.Or maybe I shouldn't use such expression in sympy?

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.quantum import *
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D

x,y,z = symbols("x y z")
C = CoordSys3D('C')
psi = symbols("psi", cls=Function)

r = DifferentialOperator((x*C.i+ y*C.j+ z*C.k)*psi(x,y,z), psi(x,y,z))


px = DifferentialOperator(-I * hbar *C.i * Derivative(psi(x,y,z), x), psi(x,y,z))

comm = Commutator(r, px)
comm.doit()
```

As above, I tried the vector module， but the final commutator won't be evaluated.
What I need is to calculate the commutator of the position operator and the momentum operator in a three dimensional way.